# PostgreSQL - Unable to use PARTITION BY when multiple columns are involved

Tags: postgresql, window

Suppose I have a table with 5 columns:

- YEAR
- COMPANY
- DEPARTMENT
- EMPLOYEE
- SALES

And I wanted to query the results to get the following results:

- COMPANY
- DEPARTMENT
- EMPLOYEE
- SUM(SALES)

The additional requirement being that the COMPANY with the Maximum Sales (across all departments) shows first, and then the DEPARTMENT within the company with the Maximum Sales shows first for the company, and the same for EMPLOYEE column.

SUCCESS: The following query works fine when I query ONLY for the COMPANY:

```
 SELECT company,
       SUM(sales)
FROM   company_sales
GROUP  BY company
ORDER  BY SUM(SUM(sales))
            over (
              PARTITION BY company) DESC,
          company;
```

SUCCESS: The following query works fine when I group by COMPANY & DEPARTMENT:

```
SELECT company,
       department,
       SUM(sales)
FROM   company_sales
GROUP  BY company,
          department
ORDER  BY SUM(SUM(sales))
            over (
              PARTITION BY company) DESC,
          SUM(SUM(sales))
            over (
              PARTITION BY department) DESC,
          company,
          department;
```

FAILURE: The following query FAILS when I group by COMPANY, DEPARTMENT & EMPLOYEE:

```
SELECT company,
       department,
       employee,
       SUM(sales)
FROM   company_sales
GROUP  BY company,
          department,
          employee
ORDER  BY SUM(SUM(sales))
            over (
              PARTITION BY company) DESC,
          SUM(SUM(sales))
            over (
              PARTITION BY department) DESC,
          SUM(SUM(sales))
            over (
              PARTITION BY employee) DESC,
          company,
          department,
          employee;
```

Here's the above query with Data for your Use:

```
WITH COMPANY_SALES AS (
SELECT  2010    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-A' as department, 'Employee-A-A-1' as employee,  100 as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-A' as department, 'Employee-A-A-2' as employee,  101 as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-A' as department, 'Employee-A-A-3' as employee,  102 as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-B' as department, 'Employee-A-B-1' as employee,  50  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-B' as department, 'Employee-A-B-2' as employee,  51  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-B' as department, 'Employee-A-B-3' as employee,  52  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-B' as department, 'Employee-A-B-4' as employee,  53  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-B' as department, 'Employee-A-B-5' as employee,  54  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-C' as department, 'Employee-A-C-1' as employee,  80  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-C' as department, 'Employee-A-C-2' as employee,  81  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-C' as department, 'Employee-A-C-3' as employee,  82  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-A' as department, 'Employee-B-A-1' as employee,  20  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-A' as department, 'Employee-B-A-2' as employee,  21  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-A' as department, 'Employee-B-A-3' as employee,  22  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-B' as department, 'Employee-B-B-1' as employee,  90  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-B' as department, 'Employee-B-B-2' as employee,  91  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-B' as department, 'Employee-B-B-3' as employee,  92  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-B' as department, 'Employee-B-B-4' as employee,  93  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-B' as department, 'Employee-B-B-5' as employee,  94  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-B' as department, 'Employee-B-B-6' as employee,  95  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-C' as department, 'Employee-B-C-1' as employee,  40  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-D' as department, 'Employee-B-D-1' as employee,  60  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-D' as department, 'Employee-B-D-2' as employee,  61  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-D' as department, 'Employee-B-D-3' as employee,  62  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-D' as department, 'Employee-B-D-4' as employee,  63  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-C' as company, 'Department-C-A' as department, 'Employee-C-A-1' as employee,  20  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-C' as company, 'Department-C-A' as department, 'Employee-C-A-2' as employee,  21  as sales
UNION SELECT    2010    as year, 'Company-C' as company, 'Department-C-A' as department, 'Employee-C-A-3' as employee,  22  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-A' as department, 'Employee-A-A-1' as employee,  30  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-A' as department, 'Employee-A-A-2' as employee,  29  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-A' as department, 'Employee-A-A-3' as employee,  28  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-A' as department, 'Employee-A-A-4' as employee,  27  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-B' as department, 'Employee-A-B-1' as employee,  45  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-B' as department, 'Employee-A-B-2' as employee,  25  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-B' as department, 'Employee-A-B-3' as employee,  78  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-B' as department, 'Employee-A-B-4' as employee,  23  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-C' as department, 'Employee-A-C-1' as employee,  12  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-C' as department, 'Employee-A-C-2' as employee,  54  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-C' as department, 'Employee-A-C-3' as employee,  79  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-A' as department, 'Employee-B-A-1' as employee,  34  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-A' as department, 'Employee-B-A-2' as employee,  89  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-A' as department, 'Employee-B-A-3' as employee,  60  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-B' as department, 'Employee-B-B-1' as employee,  23  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-B' as department, 'Employee-B-B-2' as employee,  62  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-B' as department, 'Employee-B-B-3' as employee,  45  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-B' as department, 'Employee-B-B-4' as employee,  78  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-B' as department, 'Employee-B-B-5' as employee,  45  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-B' as department, 'Employee-B-B-6' as employee,  9   as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-C' as department, 'Employee-B-C-1' as employee,  73  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-D' as department, 'Employee-B-D-1' as employee,  93  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-D' as department, 'Employee-B-D-2' as employee,  27  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-D' as department, 'Employee-B-D-3' as employee,  59  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-D' as department, 'Employee-B-D-4' as employee,  73  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-C' as company, 'Department-C-A' as department, 'Employee-C-A-1' as employee,  54  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-C' as company, 'Department-C-A' as department, 'Employee-C-A-2' as employee,  67  as sales
UNION SELECT    2011    as year, 'Company-C' as company, 'Department-C-A' as department, 'Employee-C-A-3' as employee,  84  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-A' as department, 'Employee-A-A-1' as employee,  78  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-A' as department, 'Employee-A-A-2' as employee,  69  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-A' as department, 'Employee-A-A-3' as employee,  45  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-A' as department, 'Employee-A-A-4' as employee,  69  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-B' as department, 'Employee-A-B-1' as employee,  24  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-B' as department, 'Employee-A-B-2' as employee,  35  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-B' as department, 'Employee-A-B-3' as employee,  89  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-B' as department, 'Employee-A-B-4' as employee,  64  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-B' as department, 'Employee-A-B-5' as employee,  75  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-C' as department, 'Employee-A-C-1' as employee,  15  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-A' as company, 'Department-A-C' as department, 'Employee-A-C-2' as employee,  38  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-A' as department, 'Employee-B-A-1' as employee,  46  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-A' as department, 'Employee-B-A-2' as employee,  85  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-A' as department, 'Employee-B-A-3' as employee,  63  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-B' as department, 'Employee-B-B-1' as employee,  24  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-B' as department, 'Employee-B-B-2' as employee,  59  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-B' as department, 'Employee-B-B-3' as employee,  76  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-B' as department, 'Employee-B-B-4' as employee,  18  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-B' as department, 'Employee-B-B-5' as employee,  94  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-B' as department, 'Employee-B-B-6' as employee,  55  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-C' as department, 'Employee-B-C-1' as employee,  69  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-D' as department, 'Employee-B-D-1' as employee,  37  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-D' as department, 'Employee-B-D-2' as employee,  84  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-D' as department, 'Employee-B-D-3' as employee,  52  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-B' as company, 'Department-B-D' as department, 'Employee-B-D-4' as employee,  55  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-C' as company, 'Department-C-A' as department, 'Employee-C-A-1' as employee,  78  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-C' as company, 'Department-C-A' as department, 'Employee-C-A-2' as employee,  94  as sales
UNION SELECT    2012    as year, 'Company-C' as company, 'Department-C-A' as department, 'Employee-C-A-3' as employee,  21  as sales
)
SELECT company,
       department,
       employee,
       SUM(sales)
FROM company_sales
GROUP  BY company,
          department,
          employee
ORDER  BY SUM(SUM(sales))
            over (
              PARTITION BY company) DESC,
          SUM(SUM(sales))
            over (
              PARTITION BY department) DESC,
          SUM(SUM(sales))
            over (
              PARTITION BY employee) DESC,
          company,
          department,
          employee;
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I realized that the results of the above query are looking good.I must not have a good data set to represent my problem, as the same query in my production dataset (with a different domain) doesn't work.The order of the results are not accurate.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your example dataset, departments are unique, so you can:

```
PARTITION BY department
```

However, if more than one company can have the same department, you'd need:

```
PARTITION BY company, department
```

---

Side note: since you're grouping on `company, department, employee` the third `over` clause is superfluous.  You could simplify by omitting it:

```
ORDER  BY SUM(SUM(sales)) over (PARTITION BY company) DESC
,         SUM(SUM(sales)) over (PARTITION BY company, department) DESC
,         SUM(sales) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that in my example the Departments are UNIQUE. That was key.

Comment: Does order of columns matter?